# Print using for loop - Python

Tags: python

I am fairly very new to Python or any programming language for that matter. I am finding it challenging to print arbitrary text along with with iterated values from a list, using for loop. What I need is to print the whole first item of the list with arbitrary text "shutdown" and repeat the same for new text "no shutdown". Also, I want to be able to insert any text statements between the two separate outputs: Please advise. Here is more information..

**CURRENT OUTPUT: Which is not desired**

```
interface Vlan100
 shut
 no shut
interface Vlan108
 shut
 no shut
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUTS:**

*# First time printing:*

```
********* THIS IS INTERFACE OUTPUT WITH "SHUTDOWN" **********
interface Vlan100
 shutdown
interface Vlan108
 shutdown
```

** *THIS IS INTERFACE OUTPUT WITH "NO SHUTDOWN"* *****

```
*# Second time printing:*
interface Vlan100
 no shutdown
interface Vlan108
 no shutdown
```

**CODE EXTRACT, Snipped for brevity reasons.**

```
for i in servicetypes:
<snip>
<snip>
elif "ipv4 address" in i or "ipv4 address 8" in i or " ipv4 address 213" in i:
    i = re.sub(r'encapsulation dot1Q \d+\n\s','',i)
    i = re.sub(r'TenGigE[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9].','Vlan',i)
    internet = i.split("\n")
    print internet[1]
    print " shut"
    print " no shut"
```

Comment: The reasons are good, but the code contains errors. You shouldn't use any formatting tags, just use `101010` button for formatting.

Comment: If you print " shut" followed by " no shut" then of course they're both going to show.

Comment: `"ipv4 address" in i or "ipv4 address 8" in i or " ipv4 address 213" in i` is kind of redundant, assuming `i` is a string.

Comment: Thanks AndiDog, I fixed the redundancy issue but that's not relevant to issue I pointed out which is to print the output as shown in the expected output section. I can always change the code to make print the way I expect it? My apologies if I am missing something top basic here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean you want all interfaces to print "shutdown" on the first pass through the outer loop, and "no shutdown" on all subsequent passes? If not, you need to provide a better description of your intended program logic.

Comment: That's right Charles.. As depicted in Expected Output versus Current Output.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the pastebins (below). But they doesn't work. First you make massive replacements no a file (for no apparent reason, mind commenting your code?) then you have two regexps looking for something in the file that does not exist. Try to prepare your questions better. Have working code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: To get forward: What are you trying to achieve? You have a big file of some sort of log. What is it you want to do with that file?

Comment: Thanks Lennart :) Well it's a Cisco device IOS based configuration ("DIC3") logfile) that I am interested to convert/parse into a different format (IOS XR) for which expects different formatting but using the values. So all I am doing is parsing input file by substituting certain values with new values and keep the new values for later use as well extracting different kind/group of interface blocks using conditions and creating lists of items/elements out of them based on the matching fields/records in them so I can print them in  different ways after wards. BTW, I am using Python 2.7..

Comment: Also, I have a draft in PDF format which explains the requirement in quite detail which I created right before started to learn the Python for the same purpose :) Not sure how I can share that here.. Anyhow, there is a lot that I am doing in the script other than printing shutdown and no shutdown :) it's why I didn't want to post the whole code in the first here as that would create confusions... Thanks a million for reading this and being patient with me.. Cheers

Comment: Well, I have been able to print screen first two pages of the pdf draft illustrating the requirement. This is from another file similar to DIC3 (being called by the code). Here are the details..

Conversion Page 1 = http://tinypic.com/r/24xpbtf/7
Conversion Page 2 = http://tinypic.com/r/15d45g7/7

As for the issue,this post is about, it's not contained in the image files but this is to just get one an idea why code is written like that, for instance. thanks..

Thanks a lot..

Comment: Ugh. Converting one log file to another. :-( Anyhow, if you like regexps, keep doing it, I'd probably parse the file instead to find the data, and then generate a new one from that data. YYMV. In any case, your problem right now is that you are looking for regexps that doesn't exist in the file, so both `staticroute` and `interfacestypes` is empty. So whatever error you have in the rest of the code is hidden by this.

Comment: :) staticroute can be removed. However, for interfacestypes, it's working fine as it's finding the value from the memory resulted in substitution of "interface FastEthernet." to "interface TenGigE" using re.sub(r'FastEthernet\d*/\d*',Teng,f.read()). And then, at later stage, I am replacing TenGigE with Vlan which is also fine using the following lines of code:

        i = re.sub(r'encapsulation dot1Q \d+\n\s','',i)
        i = re.sub(r'TenGigE[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9].','Vlan',i)

The code is working fine on my computer though. I am using Eclipse (Pydev) IDE with Python 2.7 as interpreter :/

Comment: Lennart - Thanks a lot - It's fixed now with your help. I put the following
for what in (" shut", " no shut"):
right before the subsequent iterations (for loop) and it works like a charm :). The code is looking funny but doing the job for me and it's what I care, as a beginner. Thanks a million.. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Currently you do this:

```
print " shut"
print " no shut"
```

The result of that is:

```
shut
no shut
```

As expected. If you want it to print "shut" when it shuts down and "no shut" when it doesn't, you need a test:

```
if shutdown(interface):
    print "shut"
else:
    print "no shut"
```

Or something similar.

---

(Edit: OK, you answered that, you want the above, not the below, so ignore this part.

If however, you just want to print

```
interface Vlan100
 shut
interface Vlan108
 shut
interface Vlan100
 no shut
interface Vlan108
 no shut
```

Then you need two separate loops.

It's not exactly clear what you want or what you are trying to do, though.)

OK. here is how to get that output:

```
for what in (" shut", " no shut"):
    for iface in ('vlan100', 'vlan108'):
         print "interface", iface
         print what
```

Comment: Thanks Lennart - I wanted the later part.

interface Vlan100
 shut
interface Vlan108
 shut
interface Vlan100
 no shut
interface Vlan108
 no shut

Comment: Can I know what the code is going to look like to achieve 
the following? I don't any conditional printing here.. Just the following output.. 

interface Vlan100
 shut
interface Vlan108
 shut
interface Vlan100
 no shut
interface Vlan108
 no shut

Comment: Thanks Lennart for the code, but I am already in a for loop and this is not a new code so it's creating many iterations. Using your code I am getting the following. How can I post the full code here? besides, interface Vlan100 and interface Vlan800 should come from list instead through iteration.

Here's what I am getting

interface vlan100
 shut
interface vlan108
 shut
interface vlan100
 no shut
interface vlan108
 no shut
interface vlan100
 shut
interface vlan108
 shut
interface vlan100
 no shut
interface vlan108
 no shut
..... So on!!

Comment: You can put the fill code on a pastebin site and link. They come from a list (or well tuple) that is iterated over. I'm sorry I'm not going to be able to explain this more carefully to you, you need to go through more tutorials/books to understand the fundamentals of programming.

Comment: CODE: http://python.pastebin.com/N5sHU9JR
Input file "DIC3": http://pastebin.com/T0FRGkRp

Answer (score 1):

Well, a few mistakes.  1) Python arrays are indexed at 0.  So your call to `print internet[1]` is printing the second element of your array.  Given you claim in your description "What I need is to print the whole first item of the list", that call should be `print internet[0]`

Secondly, you claim that you need to print the string "shutdown" or "no shutdown"... yet you are printing "shut" and "no shut".  Change those print statements to use "shutdown" and "no shutdown".

Furthermore, you need to make some conditional to determine whether to print the string "shutdown" or "no shutdown"; right now you are printing both.

Comment: I82Much - Thank you for pointing that out as I composed this email in rush. Consider the code where you pointed out as errors in the code and here's the correct one if you like: It's the second value of list which I have no issues in printing the issue is with printing "shutdown" and "no shutdown"..

print internet[1]
    print " shutdown"
    print " no shutdown"

Comment: email? Computer programming is an art that requires you to be *exact*. Try to not call questions emails. :)

Comment: Never mind!! It's my 3rd day using/learning any computer language and I am able to write or atleast achieve some decent results . I don't even consider my self programmer or an artist. Apologies if I offended you programming gods here. Hoping to see some sort of support here. Also, never knew calling questions as emails is illegal here :) atleast in the world of programming.. Thanks for your time though.. Cheers

Comment: @user531942: "Also, never knew calling questions as emails is illegal here".  It's not illegal.  It's ill-advised.  These are not "emails".  These are "questions".  Exact matters a lot.  A real lot.  Please try to be really exact all the time, or you'll never learn to program.

Comment: Trust me, I am trying.. So far, I have found it fun and need to stay motivated with help of gurus like yourself :-) Cheers

Comment: @user531942: Not bad for the third day. But I think you need to go through some more tutorials and exercises before you can tackle something complex. You have a lot of code that doesn't seem to do anything useful. Try to simplify the problem into little bits and do one thing at a time.